# ModelMultipleChoiceField raises "Enter a list of values."

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form:

```
class BaseCommandForm(forms.Form):
    devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Device.objects.filter(token__isnull=False).order_by('division__name', 'pk'),
        widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'devices-list', 'multiple': 'multiple', })
    )

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.fields['devices'].label_from_instance = BaseCommandForm.label_for_device_instance

    @staticmethod
    def label_for_device_instance(obj: Device) -> str:
        return f'{obj.division.name} -> #{obj.pk}'
```

It's rendered as select:

```
<select name="devices" class="devices-list select form-control is-invalid select2-hidden-accessible" multiple="" id="id_devices" data-select2-id="id_devices" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true"> 
   <option value="1" data-select2-id="6">Test Division -&gt; #1</option> 
   <option value="2" data-select2-id="7">Test Division -&gt; #2</option> 
   ...
</select>
```

My view:

```
class CreateCommandView(CompanyMixin, GroupRequiredMixin, FormView):
    template_name = 'commands/create.html'
    group_required = 'company_admin'  # TODO: Change group
    success_url = reverse_lazy('companies:commands:list')

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        command_type = self.request.GET.get('type')
        if command_type not in [TYPE_UPDATE_CONFIG, TYPE_SHOW_MESSAGE, TYPE_DOWNLOAD_FILE, TYPE_UNINSTALL_APP, TYPE_WIPE_DEVICE, TYPE_UNINSTALL_AGENT]:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest()

        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def get_form_class(self):
        command_type = self.request.GET.get('type')

        if command_type == TYPE_UPDATE_CONFIG:
            form_class = UpdateConfigCommandForm
        elif command_type == TYPE_SHOW_MESSAGE:
            form_class = ShowMessageCommandForm
        elif command_type == TYPE_DOWNLOAD_FILE:
            form_class = DownloadFileCommandForm
        elif command_type == TYPE_UNINSTALL_APP:
            form_class = UninstallAppCommandForm
        elif command_type == TYPE_WIPE_DEVICE:
            form_class = WipeDeviceCommandForm
        elif command_type == TYPE_UNINSTALL_AGENT:
            form_class = UninstallAgentCommandForm
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Invalid type: {command_type}')

        return form_class

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        context['command_type'] = self.request.GET.get('type')

        return context

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        print(self.request.POST)
        return super().form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

I select two values and submit the form:

[image]

And it returns error:

[image]

I see only one device in `cleaned_data.get('devices')` with the debugger (and as you can see on the screenshot it renders only one device on error).

`request.POST`:

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['sdlVFQVnjoEz2uQHpFvv00OqcypZKjOCP7v5wYIdgqx5iUhikjNuCIGW5Q9Qbopr'], 'devices': ['6']}>
```

What's wrong?

Comment: How do you process te form here? Can you share relevant parts of your view?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sure, see the update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the issue was in widget. `SelectMultiple` is required for correct body parsing:

```
    devices = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
        queryset=Device.objects.filter(token__isnull=False).order_by('division__name', 'pk'),
        widget=forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'devices-list', 'multiple': 'multiple', })
    )
```